# I can't hard reset or install any apps on my android device

Tags: twrp, xolo

I decided to flash my flash my device (Xolo Era 4k) using TWRP. I got little confused after booting in **TWRP** mode. Then I somehow managed to let my device Boot in normal mode. Then I found that I can't install any apps or apks.

Even hard reset didn't work. My Device was restarting normally even when I tried to hard reset (hard reset menu wont appear).

Device Info:

1. Xolo era 4k
2. Android Version 5.0.1
3. Non-rooted device

Xolo era 4k
Android Version 5.0.1
Non-rooted device

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible reason, You Can’t Install Apps on Your Android Phone

Your Android phone doesn’t have enough storage left
Your phone’s cache could be causing the problem
Your Android OS is too old and needs updating
A factory reset of your phone may fix the problem
You’re using a screen dimming app

Comment: I do have a lot of space.
Yes I checked the allocated size of each apps, it shows 0.0 MB.
Factory reset is not working.
I don't have any screen dimming app.